# how can I get a position of checked singleItemDialog position in android studio and replace into checkedItem?

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, box

I want to store position of Gujarati, Hindi and English and store into chechSum. so once it's selected, it remain selected when I open dialog again.
    ----------
    `final String[] languageList = {"ગુજરાતી", "हिन्दी", "English"};
                int checkItem = 0;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Language...");
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(languageList, checkItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        if (languageList[i].equals("ગુજરાતી")) {
                            //Gujarati
                            setLanguage("gu");
                            recreate();
                        } else if (languageList[i].equals("हिन्दी")) {
                            //Hindi
                            setLanguage("hi");
                            recreate();
                        } else if (languageList[i].equals("English")) {
                            //English
                            setLanguage("en");
                            recreate();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        ;
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                int selectedPosition = (alertDialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                toast(String.valueOf(selectedPosition));
                alertDialog.show();
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You get the index of the clicked item as "int i" in the onClick method and can use it to select the correct item from the languageList by calling languageList.get(i);

Retrieving the selected position before showing the alertdialog does not work, the user has to interact with the dialog first.

Comment: where I have to call languageList.get(i); and how can I pass that value in checkItem variable??